# Select/print data from subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery

In my application I have a table "user", a table "role", and a table "userroles". Userroles is simple table consisting of `user, role`, where `user` corresponds to the `id` column of the `user` table. As user can have multiple roles, and obviously multiple users can have the same role. Now I wish to find all users who do NOT have the specific role (`private_account`), and I wish to list them as `(user_id, new-inserted-role-id)` for further processing.

```
SELECT u.id, r.id
FROM public."user" AS u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
    SELECT ur.user
    FROM public."userroles" as ur
    INNER JOIN public."role" as r
    ON ur.role=r.id
    WHERE r."roleDescription"='private_account'
)
```

However this complains that the table `r` does not exist.

`ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ur"`

How can I do this?

So for clarity: if `private_account` would have id `2` and I a user 1 which does not have this ID the return would look like:

```
USER | role
1    | 2
2    | 2
```

The role reported is independent on what the user actually has. I *could* do this manually and do a select like below. However this has the huge disadvantage that I have to manually update the sql if I move to a different database (since the ID might not correspond to the actual role name).

```
SELECT u.id, 2
...
```

The further processing is basically using the return from the select as `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO public."userroles"
SELECT u.id, r.id
FROM public."user" AS u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
    SELECT ur.user
    FROM public."userroles" as ur
    INNER JOIN public."role" as r
    ON ur.role=r.id
    WHERE r."roleDescription"='private_account'
)
```

Comment: What is "actual_role_id" supposed to be?  Each role that each qualifying user does have, or just the role id for 'private_account' (which is the one they **don't** have, in order to meet the qualification)?

Comment: @jjanes the role they don't have - just so I can insert it as a new role.

Comment: There is no need to use "quoted_identifiers" when unquoted_identifiers work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Create tables:

```
postgres=# create table "user" (
    id int primary key,
    name text unique);
postgres=# create table "role" (
    id int primary key,
    name text unique);
postgres=# create table "userroles" (
    "user" int references "user",
    "role" int references "role",
    primary key("user", "role")
);
```

Populate test data

```
postgres=# insert into "user" values (1, 'privateuser'), (2, 'publicuser');
postgres=# insert into "role" values (1, 'private_account'), (2, 'other_role');
postgres=# insert into userroles values (1,1), (1,2), (2,2);
```

Find all users and their roles:

```
postgres=# SELECT u.id, u.name as "user", r.id, r.name as "role"
    FROM "user" u
    LEFT JOIN "userroles" ur ON ur.user=u.id
    LEFT JOIN "role" r ON r.id=ur.role;

 id |    user     | id |      role       
----+-------------+----+-----------------
  1 | privateuser |  1 | private_account
  1 | privateuser |  2 | other_role
  2 | publicuser  |  2 | other_role
(3 rows)
```

Find all users who do NOT have the specific role:

```
postgres=# select u.id, u.name as "user", r.id, r.name as "role"
    FROM "user" u
    LEFT JOIN userroles ur ON ur.user=u.id
    LEFT JOIN "role" r ON r.id=ur.role
    WHERE u.id NOT IN (
        SELECT "user" FROM userroles ur2, "role" r2
        WHERE r2.id=ur2.role AND r2.name='private_account');

 id |    user    | id |    role       
----+------------+----+-------------
  2 | publicuser |  2 | other_role
(1 row)
```

This last query is your answer.

Comment: That shows the `other_role` however I wish to get the id of the `private_account` role. - So I can then use that *result* to insert back into the database and give all users which have not yet private account role the private account role.

Comment: Quote: "I wish to find all users who do NOT have the specific role (private_account), and I wish to list them as (user_id, actual_role_id)" - is this not what you wanted?

Comment: I should rephrase what I want with `actual_role_id` - I mean with that the new "to be inserted" role id, not the "existing role id".

Comment: then you need to rewrite the query ... remove the 1st join to "role", modify the SELECT list  and add DISTINCT so you don't insert same row twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do another subquery:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    (select r2.id from public."role" as r2 where r2."roleDescription"='private_account') as missing_role_id 
FROM public."user" AS u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
    SELECT ur.user
    FROM public."userroles" as ur
    INNER JOIN public."role" as r
    ON ur.role=r.id
    WHERE r."roleDescription"='private_account'
)
```

If you object to 'private_account' appearing twice in the query, you an put it behind a CTE.

```
WITH j as (select id from public."role" where "roleDescription"='private_account')
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    (select id from j) as missing_role_id 
FROM public."user" AS u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
    SELECT ur.user
    FROM public."userroles" as ur
    WHERE ur.role=(select id from j)
)
```